# Unable to cast Generic class as java entity class

Tags: spring, hibernate, dao

I tried to do Generic Dao class Implementation. But i stucked with an error like this-

```
 "sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class"
```

My generic class name accessing method code is,

```
 protected Class<T> getEntityClass() {
        if (entityClass == null) {
            entityClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        }
        return entityClass;
    }
```

I dont understand this problem. Please help me.

**Edit**

Interface -

```
import java.util.List;

public interface IGenericDao<T> {

    void update(T entity);

    T merge(T entity);

    int save(T entity);

    void delete(T entity);

    T find(int id);

    List<T> findAll(int PageNo) throws Exception;

    List<T> find();

    void saveOrUpdate(T entity);

}
```

Class,

```
public class Services<T> extends IGenericDaoImpl<T> {


}
```

Abstract Class -

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public abstract class IGenericDaoImpl<T> implements IGenericDao<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



    protected Class<T> getEntityClass() {
        if (entityClass == null) {
            entityClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            //entityClass=(Class<T>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), IGenericDaoImpl.class);

        }
        return entityClass;
    }


    public void update(T entity) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(entity);
    }


    public T merge(T entity) {
        return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(entity);
    }


    public int save(T entity) {

        return (Integer) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    }


    public void delete(T entity) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
    }


    public T find(int id) {
        return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(getEntityClass(), id);
    }


    public List<T> find() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from " + getEntityClass().getName()).list();
    }


    public void saveOrUpdate(T entity) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }


    public List<T> findAll(int PageNo) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("::::"+getEntityClass());

        int maxresult=5;

        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(getEntityClass())

                            .setFirstResult((PageNo-1)*maxresult)
                            .setMaxResults(maxresult);

        //System.out.println("Criteria: "+criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()));

        return criteria.list();
    }



}
```

Comment: how do you extend your generic class? please provide your code. it seems that you are missing `generics`.

Comment: try this and tell me if it works. remove `abstract` from `IGenericDaoImpl`, use `getEntityClass` in its default constructor, use this constructor in `Services` constructor by calling `super` and also remove the `generics` from `Services`. Services should also not point to some T but an actual class. did you post it incomplete?

Comment: Can't avoid  abstract class, because abstract class implementation is used for bean configuration.